# How to make unordered lists responsive with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Right now I have an unordered list like this:

[image]

and in mobile view it looks like this:

[image]

Code (HTML / CSS)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  flex: auto ;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list 1<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>list 2<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>List 3<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>list 4<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

How would I go about making the lists responsive? As in maybe having two columns per row in mobile screen.

Comment: You seem to be using `display: flex` like it's some kind of magic responsiveness bullet... You need to specify behaviour like minimum sizes, break points, `flex-wrap: wrap`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a @media query breakpoint.  In this example, when the screen is 991px or slimmer, I apply flex-wrap to the parent, and a flex-basis of 50% to the children.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list 1<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>list 2<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>List 3<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>list 4<br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obligatory link to my favorite flexbox guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/